# High-performance merging of ordered sets

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, c++11, real-time-updates

The desire is to keep a set of numbers sorted (ascending or descending, but examples below show only ascending). The data structure representation for utmost speed is the question.

Say an aggregating program continously getting packets of numbers from many different monitoring agents, for example through a network. The idea is to keep them sorted at all times fast. As an example, you might get these packets (using ints but double is the actual case) in sequence:

```
A = [1, 3, 4, 6]
B = [1, 2, 3]
C = [2, 3, 5]
A = [2, 4, 7, 8]
```

and so on. After the first packet, your data structure in your aggregator will be already sorted (the data structure remembers what source each number in the sort refers to) :

> [1, 3, 4, 6] => Event

after the next packet, since it is a new source, the data structure will look like this

> [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6] => Event

after the next packet,

> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6] => Event

and now since A sent new packet, we have to get find the old values of A, and replacing them with the new, finally ending up with a new sort. The replacing and sorting can happen seperately or not (inplace), the goal is extreme speed:

> [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8] => Event

Note that when you get the second A, all the old As have to be "replaced" by the new As packet while maintaining a sort. After each packet is sorted into the data structure, it is copied and needs to be sent as an "event". These packets are coming furiously and continously at the merging-sorting algorithm every few microseconds.

* What is the best data structure to do this? Maybe Splay Tree or AVL tree? ***

Comment: At least leave a comment if you downvote, so that the OP can improve the question.

Comment: The fastest imaginable algorithm is [quantum bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Comment: Will the numbers in each packet always be sorted? aka: Your examples A, B, C, and A are each sorted from low to high. (If so, you can take advantage of that in your sort).

Comment: Are you not satisfied with [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) or [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)? They also have insertion functions with "hints" (iterators).

Comment: DyP, would that work with doubles? His examples use ints but he says he needs doubles (just wondering for myself; I'm not sure).

Comment: @user1676605 You should change your title to better reflect your actual scenario/question.

Comment: Collin, The numbers will always be already sorted amongst themselves.

Comment: @CollinJSimpson The `double` fulfils all requirements for the `key` template parameter with the default comparison `std::less` AFAIK.

Comment: DyP, I am not enamored of the title. I will take suggestions and change it accordingly.

Comment: DyP, std::multiset and std::multimap may work. I doubt they would come close to a hand written version using splay or AVL tree, but that is the question. I do not know what the underlying mechanism multiset or multimap uses. If you can post a simple example, I can time it.

Comment: I'm not keen on editing the title myself, but does "Merging ordered sets" describe it appropriately? Many users might be upset by the "fastest imaginable" phrase.

Comment: Why do they need to be sorted at the end?  As in, what is observing the data structure, how, and what properties can we exploit?  What's wrong with having a few sorted arrays and giving the observer a fancy iterator?

Comment: With those questions asked, it's unlikely that you can beat `multiset` or `multimap` by much.  Data structures that accomplish dynamic sorting tend to be rather slow.

Comment: @tmyklebu IMO your iterator remark is should be an answer. It's faster than the `multiset` approach in many scenarios.

Comment: @DyP: The problem is that this question is still too vague.

Comment: tmyklebu , I will try to make the question even more explicit when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be the fastest data structure & algorithm for your particular purpose I guess, but it may be fast enough. Test it yourself.

Note that a `std::forward_list` or even a `std::vector` might be faster depending on the actual scenario (-> constant factors in big-O-notation).

[tmyklebu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1834147/tmyklebu) mentioned another approach [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046379/high-performance-merging-of-ordered-sets?noredirect=1#comment26405610_18046379): depending on the scenario, it might be faster to merge on-demand, e.g. storing all data sets individually and merging them into a `vector` to pass to the event handler, or even using a "merging" iterator (whose increment gets the next element of the individual data sets).

Further performance improvements may be achieved by using a custom memory pool -> custom allocator.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// inserts a sorted range into the `to` container
template < typename To, typename InputIt >
void insert_new_sorted(To& to,
                       InputIt beg_old, InputIt end_old,
                       InputIt beg_new, InputIt end_new)
{
    auto const& comp = to.value_comp();
    typename To::iterator i = to.begin();

    // might improve performance: don't remove elements which are in both
    // ranges (old and new)
    while(beg_old != end_old && beg_new != end_new)
    {
        if(comp(*beg_old, *beg_new))
        {
            // remove old element
            i = to.find(*beg_old);  // "slow", no hint :(
            i = to.erase(i);
            ++beg_old;
        }else if(comp(*beg_new, *beg_old))
        {
            // insert new element
            // using the hint to achieve better performance
            i = to.insert(i, *beg_new);
            ++beg_new;
        }else
        {
            // both equal, do nothing
            ++beg_new;
            ++beg_old;
        }
    }

    // remove remaining old elements
    for(; beg_old != end_old; ++beg_old)
    {
        to.erase(to.find(*beg_old));  // "slow", no hint :(
    }

    // insert remaining new elements
    for(; beg_new != end_new; ++beg_new)
    {
        i = to.insert(i, *beg_new);
    }

    std::copy(to.begin(), to.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<typename To::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using set_t = std::multiset<double>;

    set_t const A = {1, 3, 4, 6};
    set_t const B = {1, 2, 3};
    set_t const C = {2, 3, 5};
    set_t const A2 = {2, 4, 7, 8};

    set_t result;
    insert_new_sorted(result, A.end(), A.end(), A.begin(), A.end());
    insert_new_sorted(result, B.end(), B.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
    insert_new_sorted(result, C.end(), C.end(), C.begin(), C.end());
    insert_new_sorted(result, A.begin(), A.end(), A2.begin(), A2.end());
}
```

Output:

> 1, 3, 4, 6, 
>   1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 
>   1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
>   1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8,

---

A different approach: store the iterators of the inserted elements, to speed up erasing.

Comment: DyP, thank you for your example. The thing is, A2 is not a new source, it is the same source as A. So the values of A2 have to replace the values of A - in effect, a new packet from a source invalidates its old state in the sorted set. See the original post. If you follow the packets, your list should be the same as the final list I give.

Comment: @user1676605 Fixed, though doesn't achieve high performance at two points (namely, neither `erase` nor `find` can take a hint).

Comment: DyP,Thank you. I am going to test this version against my naive version and compare. I would be extremely surprised if your version wasn't at least twice as fast as mine, although mine is the suggestion that tmyklebu makes. I will post again when done. What is more, I learned some interesting tidbits on the languate itself too.

Comment: @user1676605 Be aware of tmyklebu's approach; if you need to iterate over all elements for each "Event", then that version will be faster than `multiset`, especially if you store the individual sets as vectors (which have fast iteration).

Comment: DyP, Imo there is less copying in your version. The standard template libray loves to copy (probably to keep it functional and thread safe? But it hurts performance when that copying is not needed) But without measuring I won't know.

Comment: @user1676605 When you create a "merging iterator" as originally suggested by tmyklebu, there would be no copying at all besides storing each individual data set, which is also required in the `multiset` solution.